# Why in organ transplantation the dendritic cells can activate the T cells but not in hematopoietic stem cell transplantation?

Tags: immunology, transplantation

In the both following cases let's consider that the donor has different HLA type from the recipient.

When someones let's say kidney is transplanted into someone that has different HLA alleles, the dendritic cell from the graft goes to the lymph nodes and the T cells recognise that the dendritic cells have a foreign HLA type, hence the T cells are activated and go to kill the cells of the kidney --> rejection

This showed that even different HLA molecules are able to activate the T cells. Then how come in hematopoietic stem cell transplantation, the dendritic cells (during an infection) of the donor which have the donors' HLA type, are not able to activate the T cells of the recipient that has its own HLA type?